# HTML Table Data Export to Excel

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to extract the html data into Excel. When I click on download link it download an excel file however its blank and does not contain any data. The size of the file downloaded is 1KB. Has anyone come across 
such issue?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script lang="js">
        function fnExcelReport() {
            var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
            tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';

            tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Test Sheet</x:Name>';

            tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
            tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';

            tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
            tab_text = tab_text + $('#myTable').html();
            tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';

            var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';

            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

            if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
                if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                    var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
                        type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
                    });
                    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Test file.xls');
                }
            } else {
                $('#test').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
                $('#test').attr('download', 'Test file.xls');
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="test" onClick="javascript:fnExcelReport();">download</a>

    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right: 30px;"><b>Name</b>

                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 30px;"><b>Age</b>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tester1</td>
                <td>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tester2</td>
                <td>29</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tester3</td>
                <td>17</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No downloaded excel is not blank, it has data that is in 'tab_text' variable, 
try opening excel file with notepad. and what kind of data do you want to be kept in excel? keep it as rows of '\n' separated and columns with ',' separated.

Comment: I want the html table data to be shown in excel once I open the downloaded excel. Can you please tell me how can I do it?